# Завершение процесса с использованием Dll C#

Tags: c#, dll

Завершение процесса с использованием Dll C#. Захотел создать dll, какая бы завершала процессы, но не получилось.

```
public static string notepad()
{
    Process process = Process.Start("notepad.exe");
     process.Kill();

}
```

Что не так?

Comment: Мож чуть поподробнее расскажите что не получится и какое сообщение вылетает.

Comment: Судя по всему ничего не вылетает: процесс создается и сразу рубается - чего вы ждете от етого чудо-кода? Чтобы убедиться добавьте "слип" между старт и кил.

Comment: Ошибка 1 "DLLKill.Class1.notepad()": не все ветви кода возвращают значение C:\Users\SuperUser\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\DLLKill\DLLKill\Class1.cs 13 30 DLLKill

Comment: return string.Empty;

Comment: Скорее всего,Вы пытаетесь завершить процесс ещё до его полного порождения (`Process.Start` возвращается слишком быстро, не дожидаясь инициализации всех внутренних структур).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string killNameProcess = "notepad";
Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName(killNameProcess);
processes.First().Kill();
```

Comment: Спасибо но мне надо не по имени а по процессу

Comment: Что значит по процессу?
(по имени вы получаете процесс, а потом уже убиваете его).

Comment: Можете перебрать все процессы и посмотреть путь к исполняемому файлу, если имени недостаточно.

Answer (score 1):

```
Process[] proc = Process.GetProcesses();
foreach (Process process in proc)
    if (process.ProcessName == "notepad")
        process.Kill();
```